# Insertion Sort in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I'm trying to self teach myself Introduction to Algorithms by CLRS and I just got done trying to program the Insertion Sort algorithm. The algorithm is taken directly from the book but I'm not too confident with my Java code. The sorting part is not correct. If someone could point out my mistake, that would be fantastic!

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] A = {5,6,8,9,1,2,3};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(A));
    InsertionSort(A);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(A));
}

public static void InsertionSort(int[] A){
    for(int j = 1; j < A.length; j++){
        int key = A[j];
        int i = j - 1;
        while(i > 1 && A[i] > key){
            A[i + 1] = A[i];
            i = i - 1;
        }
        A[i + 1] = key;
    }
}
```

Comment: So your sorting algorithm's sorting part is not correct?

Comment: Now I'm confused. The algorithm made sense on paper.

Comment: @PhamTrung I know that index position in Java begins at 0 but for the Insertion Sort algorithm, you start at the second element of the array, which in this case, is 1.

Comment: @PhamTrung They are doing the faster version which does not swap inside the loop. And element `0` doesn't get considered as you need two elements to consider a swap so it starts at 1 and **should** compare to `A[i-1]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static void insertionSort(int[] A){
    for(int j = 1; j < A.length; j++){
        int key = A[j];
        int i = j; //change - don't -1
        while(i > 0 && A[i-1] > key){ //change here, must go from 0 and note change to index
            A[i] = A[i - 1]; //change here
            i = i - 1;
        }
        A[i] = key; //change here
    }
}
```

Comment: For the array {5,6,8,9,1,2,3}, I'm getting [5, 1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 9]. Is this some kind of off-by-one error?

Comment: Yes, but it's yours not mine! :p Try copying my code exactly.

Comment: I bet you left `while(i > 1` there

Comment: You got it. Stupid little mistake.

Comment: By the way, I referred to the sudo-code on the wiki article to fix yours: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort You might find it useful.